# I need to add "Authorization" to headers without Postman

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, postman

How i can add "Authorization" header in code, i use nodejs and express in my app, this is to do a login and i want to login without passing the "Authorization" header with Postman, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your Node.js code makes an HTTP request using [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html#httprequesturl-options-callback), it can insert an authorization header for Basic authentication as follows:

```js
http.request(url, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic " + Buffer.from("username:password").toString("base64")
  }
})
```